# AWS CLI: cloudwatch describe-alarms filter by namespace

Tags: amazon-web-services

From the AWS CLI docs,

[aws cloudwatch describe-alarms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/describe-alarms.html) does not have a `--namespace` argument to filter results.

On the other hand,

[aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html) does have it.

Is it at all possible to filter the alarms by namespace with the AWS CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *[--query option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html#cli-usage-output-filter)* in aws cli.  The --query parameter accepts strings that are compliant with the [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/) specification. It is pretty powerful tool to express filtering options.

For your use case

```
aws cloudwatch describe-alarms  --query 'MetricAlarms[?Namespace==`AWS/DynamoDB`]'
```

Comment: This filters the results *after* fetching them. It would be more efficient to filter the results *before* fetching. I would assume that the `--namespace` argument (from `get-metric-statistics`) does so, but I couldn't find it in the [source](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/search?q=get+metric+statistics&type=Code)

Comment: How would you do if you wanted to ask where namespace is *LIKE* AWS/DynamoDB ? or any regex that would match a particular expression?